# What do the icons in item description mean?

Tags: dark-souls

I'm very new to Dark Souls and I'm having a hard time figuring out what these icons mean by testing.

[image: screenshot of inventory with some items]

Okay, I found out how to show details, but still, not all icons are named on this screenshot:
[image: screenshot of a bandit's knife with its stats screen]

Here are the icons I'm interested in: [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Apparently, the sword icon shows how much damage the weapon deals. Although non-weapon items also have it (shields), and I could find a way to deal damage with them yet.

The icons of orange color apparently signify damage. Other colors − not sure.

What does each icon mean and how do I compare items with them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I usually compared weapons was to equip them one-by-one and check the damage of the equipped hand in my character stats. This is because the values shown in the listing are base values without scaling, which varies a lot from weapon to weapon. It's also important to note that different types of elemental damage work better against different targets.

Shields have attack because they are valid weapons, too, if equipped on the right hand. You can use them like a sword. They are often much slower or worse in attack than normal weapons, though.

### The icons you're interested in

---

[image: Armour and sword]
**Durability** - shows how quickly your item will need to be repaired.

---

[image: Bleed]
**Bleeding effectiveness** - shows how effectively the weapon causes bleeding against the enemy. Once the bleeding meter of the enemy is full, they will take a huge amount of damage based on their health.

---

[image: Poison]
**Poison effectiveness** - shows how effectively the weapon will cause poison effect on your enemy. Once their poison meter is full, they will be poisoned and take continuous damage until the meter is drained empty again.

---

[image: Divine]
**Divine effect** - effective against skeletons in the catacombs and beyond.

---

[image: Occult]
**Occult effect** - the item is more effective against certain bosses.

---

[image: Weight]
**Weight** - pretty self-explanatory. Shows how much the item weighs. Important to note when aiming for a certain type of roll.

Answer (score 2):

Those icons you listed are (in your order):
Durability, Bleed effect, Poison effect, Divine effect, Occult effect, Weight

ParamBonus are the scaling bonuses, order from best to worst is S,A,B,C,D,E, dash (-) means the weapon doesn't scale with that stat at all. Attributes listed are strength, dexterity, intelligence, faith.

ReqParam are attribute requirements that the character must meet to wield items effectively.